# Network manager and dhclient unkill in kali linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, networkmanager

I just killed my Network manager and dhclient in kali linux and I couldn't find on the web how to unkill it. Now I can't connect to WiFi anymore. Do you know how can i fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for network manager:

```
airmon-ng check kill
service NetworkManager start
```

I don't know about the dhclient.

Comment: Usually the DHCP client is started by Network Manager so running these commands should be sufficient.